# How can i get the product image size (mb/kb) , and more details about the product in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, product

How can i get the **all product image file memory size** (mb/kb), and **image title** and **image stored path** with store wise??

Comment: can you describe for what purpose you want this

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala  client was asking about that. is any possible to get that??

Comment: you want this detail for all images or for one particular image at the time?

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala , all images with product name and product image title??

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();

$product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load('product id');

Mage::log($product->getData('media_gallery'));
?>
```

in log all image url,title etc data will get.

```
2016-09-27T09:10:26+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
    [images] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [value_id] => 824
                    [file] => /h/d/hdb009_2.jpg
                    [product_id] => 447
                    [label] => 
                    [position] => 1
                    [disabled] => 0
                    [label_default] => 
                    [position_default] => 1
                    [disabled_default] => 0
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [value_id] => 825
                    [file] => /h/d/hdb008_2.jpg
                    [product_id] => 447
                    [label] => 
                    [position] => 2
                    [disabled] => 0
                    [label_default] => 
                    [position_default] => 2
                    [disabled_default] => 0
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [value_id] => 826
                    [file] => /h/d/hdb006_2.jpg
                    [product_id] => 447
                    [label] => 
                    [position] => 3
                    [disabled] => 0
                    [label_default] => 
                    [position_default] => 3
                    [disabled_default] => 0
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [value_id] => 827
                    [file] => /h/d/hdb007_2.jpg
                    [product_id] => 447
                    [label] => 
                    [position] => 4
                    [disabled] => 0
                    [label_default] => 
                    [position_default] => 4
                    [disabled_default] => 0
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [value_id] => 828
                    [file] => /h/d/hdb005_2.jpg
                    [product_id] => 447
                    [label] => 
                    [position] => 5
                    [disabled] => 0
                    [label_default] => 
                    [position_default] => 5
                    [disabled_default] => 0
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [value_id] => 880
                    [file] => /h/d/hdb010.jpg
                    [product_id] => 447
                    [label] => 
                    [position] => 6
                    [disabled] => 1
                    [label_default] => 
                    [position_default] => 6
                    [disabled_default] => 1
                )

        )

    [values] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

Comment: which file actually i have to do, ?? this how can i get the output from above coding, can you explain me briefly .

Comment: if you want to get all image of product that time this code is use.
you can creaete a test script and write above code. and check system.log file in var/log folder

Comment: , Now i have update the script in root folder, there is nothing is written on log file,., related this!. Now what i have to do?

Comment: system.log is on or not ? i modify my answer plz check. it will print this msg

Comment: no, and i want the product image file size and image title too

Comment: it will print image title nut not size

Comment: and you firstly on system.log

Comment: okay, but i need the image size , and title and image path located.

Comment: it get image title as well as location but not image size. you just check data that print in system.log file. i also incude it in my answer also

Comment: my system.log file doesnot have like above you mentioned . its showing error and warning. how can i get this @jigs parmar

Comment: first delete system.log file.. and than run the script. and in my code you put product id of product that has image

Comment: 2016-09-27T11:47:00+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
    [images] => Array
        (
        )

    [values] => Array
        (
        )

)


getting this only and there is no value returns

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45959/discussion-between-crock-and-jigs-parmar).